# Unable to parse BS tag from XML

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm having trouble parsing the image from a podcast episode, as this one isn't using the usual `<itunes:image>` tag. Any help would be appreciated. This is the code I'm using:

```
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_soup1(url1):
page = requests.get(url1)
soup1 = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
print("type: ", type(soup1))
return soup1

def get_playable_podcast1(soup1):
subjects = []
for content in soup1.find_all('item'):
    try:
        link = content.find('enclosure')
        link = link.get('url')
        print("\n\nLink: ", link)
        title = content.find('title')
        title = title.get_text()
        thumbnail = content.find('img')
        thumbnail = thumbnail.get('src')
    except AttributeError:
        continue
    item = {
            'url': link,
            'title': title,
            'thumbnail': thumbnail,
    }
    subjects.append(item)
return subjects
def compile_playable_podcast1(playable_podcast1):
items = []
for podcast in playable_podcast1:
    items.append({
        'label': podcast['title'],
        'thumbnail': podcast['thumbnail'],
        'path': podcast['url'],
        'is_playable': True,
})
return items
```

This is an example of the .XML file ([link](https://feeds.feedburner.com/porkinspolicyradio)) - either image pulled would be fine:

```
<content:encoded><![CDATA[<p>
<a href="https://ochelli.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/swansonredmond-4-21-2020-576x441.jpg">
<img src="https://ochelli.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/swansonredmond-4-21-2020-576x441.jpg" style="max-width:100%;" /></a></p>
```

[From Ochelli.com](https://ochelli.com/shotgun-shells-with-anchovies/)

Comment: Why have you shared 2 links? which one are you parsing? also can you add more code to the question..

Comment: @Yatin Sorry, not sure what that other link appeared. The link I need to parse is just the podcast XML file in the feedburner link. I've added more code to the original text, thanks for your reply. I'm just not sure why it's not pulling the <img> tag properly

Answer (score 1):

I presume, you want to get all imgs from the Ochelli.com site:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://feeds.feedburner.com/porkinspolicyradio'

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')
for c in soup.find_all('content:encoded'):
    s = BeautifulSoup(c.text, 'html.parser')
    for img in s.find_all('img'):
        if '//ochelli.com' in img['src']:
            print(img['src'])
```

Prints:

```
https://ochelli.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/Ochelli-Effect-7-14-2020.jpg
https://ochelli.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/swansonredmond-6-16-2020.jpg
https://ochelli.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/swansonredmond-6-2-2020.png
https://ochelli.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/swansonredmond-4-21-2020-576x441.jpg
https://ochelli.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/swansonredmond4-7-2020.png
https://ochelli.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/Regular-Joe-Redmond-3-24-2020-576x441.png
https://ochelli.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/mike-Pearse-2-25-2020-576x441.jpg
https://ochelli.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/swansonredmond-2-11-2020-576x441.png
https://ochelli.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/swansonredmond-1-28-2020.png
https://ochelli.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/swanson-redmond-1-14-2020.png
https://ochelli.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/swanson-redmond-12-10-2019.png
https://ochelli.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/swanson-redmond-11-26-2019.png
https://ochelli.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/11-12-2019-swanson-redmond.jpg
https://ochelli.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/swansonredmond-111-29-2019.jpg
https://ochelli.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/reg-porkins-10-1-2019.jpg
https://ochelli.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/reg-porkins-9-3-2019.jpg
https://ochelli.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/8-20-2019-pearse-swanson.jpg
https://ochelli.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/8-6-2019.png
https://ochelli.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/swansonredmond-7-23-2019.png
https://ochelli.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/zUwB2x4D.jpeg
https://ochelli.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Swanson-Redmond-6-25-2019.png
https://ochelli.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/swansonredmond-5-28-2019.jpg
```

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. That looks great, but how would I pull each image at a time and add that as the 'thumbnail' fedd along with each .mp3 and title as the other two fields for each podcast episode? I'm not sure how to add that into the format needed for this BS layout?

Comment: @leopheard it's a little bit unclear what do you want as output. Can you edit your question and put there expected output?